# Vuetify : Working with Start Time + End Time Inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input, vue-component, vuetify.js

I can't seem to spot what I missed here.

I have 2 inputs time, startTime & endTime

**startTime**

```
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
    <v-menu
        ref="menu"
        v-model="startTimeMenu"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        :nudge-right="40"
        :return-value.sync="form.values.startTime"
        transition="scale-transition"
        offset-y
        max-width="290px"
        min-width="290px"
    >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-text-field
                dense
                v-model="form.values.startTime"
                label="Start Time"
                append-icon="mdi-clock-time-four-outline"
                readonly
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
                outlined
            ></v-text-field>
        </template>
        <v-time-picker
            v-if="startTimeMenu"
            v-model="form.values.startTime"
            full-width
            @click:minute="$refs.menu.save(form.values.startTime)"
        ></v-time-picker>
    </v-menu>
</v-col>
```

**endTime**

```
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
    <v-menu
        ref="menu"
        v-model="startTimeMenu"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        :nudge-right="40"
        :return-value.sync="form.values.startTime"
        transition="scale-transition"
        offset-y
        max-width="290px"
        min-width="290px"
    >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-text-field
                dense
                v-model="form.values.startTime"
                label="Start Time"
                append-icon="mdi-clock-time-four-outline"
                readonly
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
                outlined
            ></v-text-field>
        </template>
        <v-time-picker
            v-if="startTimeMenu"
            v-model="form.values.startTime"
            full-width
            @click:minute="$refs.menu.save(form.values.startTime)"
        ></v-time-picker>
    </v-menu>
</v-col>
```

**data()**

```
data() {
        return {
            form: {
                errors: {},
                values: {
                    name: null,
                    type: 'Marketing',
                    timezone: 'America/New_York',
                    startDate: new Date(Date.now() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString().substr(0, 10),
                    endDate: new Date(Date.now() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString().substr(0, 10),
                    startTime: moment().format('HH:mm'),
                    endTime: '24:00'
                }
            },
            e1: 1,
            valid: false,
            valid2: false,
            types: ['Product', 'Marketing'],
            timezones: moment.tz.names(),
            startDateMenu: false,
            endDateMenu: false,
            startTimeMenu: false,
            endTimeMenu: false
        }
    },
```

Every time, I clicked out ... my endTime reset back to the default value.

> Note: I started to notice that only one picker will work... doesn't matter start/end time. only one seems to work when I select the minute. Whichever one I do last, It kept resetting to the default value. I think the conflict is happening somewhere...

[image]

Comment: Can you replicate the problem in codesanbox?

Comment: The `startTime` and `endTime` markup are identical in the question (copy-paste error?). Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the same ref names of two menus `<v-menu ref="menu"`.
Just rename `ref` `<v-menu ref="menu2" v-model="endTimeMenu" ... />` from `menu` to `menu2`
and also change `@click:minute="$refs.menu2.save(form.values.startTime)"`. Working correct [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-menu-problem-forked-y57fy)

Comment: That's likely just a copy-paste error in the question.

Comment: @tony19, I don’t think so, yes he made a typo, but the meaning of the problem is clear. In my demo you can check it. Just rename ref `menu2` to `menu` and you will see @code8888 problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it was an error, but the code for startTime and endTime is the same, now assuming you shared the code well, I did the following:
I copied all the code into codesandbox it gives me an error when selecting the time, but if I let the startTime code work perfectly then the error may be that you are using data from startTime for the endTime.

The solution is to use different variables for startTime and endTime.

**startTime is Working**

```html
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
    <v-menu
        ref="menu"
        v-model="startTimeMenu"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        :nudge-right="40"
        :return-value.sync="form.values.startTime"
        transition="scale-transition"
        offset-y
        max-width="290px"
        min-width="290px"
    >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-text-field
                dense
                v-model="form.values.startTime"
                label="Start Time"
                append-icon="mdi-clock-time-four-outline"
                readonly
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
                outlined
            ></v-text-field>
        </template>
        <v-time-picker
            v-if="startTimeMenu"
            v-model="form.values.startTime"
            full-width
            @click:minute="$refs.menu.save(form.values.startTime)"
        ></v-time-picker>
    </v-menu>
</v-col>
```

you can visit the project here. https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-menu-problem-r2xvl?file=/src/App.vue

if you want to see the error add the endTime code below the startTime code